# ngInclude rendering as a comment

Tags: angularjs

Everything was working fine. I added option buttons to login or register.

```
<script>
    // controller code here...

        $scope.signupfolks = function () {
            $scope.info = "You've cliked the first button!";
            $scope.actionyo = "/users/signupfolks";
        };
        $scope.loginfolks = function () {
             $scope.info = "You've cliked the second option!";
             $scope.actionyo = "/users/session";
        };
    }
</script>
```

It loads the registration page, but not the header.html. The header is defined in the layout.html

```
<body>
    <div data-ng-include="'views/header.html'" data-role="navigation">
    </div>
```

It loads views/header for the login page. It loads views/header for the auth failed, try-again page. But it doesn't load views/header for the registration page. Instead it has a comment for ngInclude

```
<!-- ngInclude: 'views/header.html' -->
```

That's what shows up instead of views/header.html.

How do I get my header.html file to render instead of the ngInclude comment?

Comment: It seems that the controller code you have added for the question doesn't have anything to do with the view code you have posted. It would help if you added the controller code for the registration page.

Comment: There's a submit button that posts the form. The controller code is for the radio option buttons in the form. What else should I post?

Comment: Add the config for your app where the routing is set up.

Comment: In addition check your browser console for JavaScript errors if they are occurring.

Comment: Also add the controller code or the html code that has the link to your registration page.

Comment: Add your [configuration block](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#configuration-blocks) that sets up the routing.

Answer (score 0):

The directive [ngInclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) is listed in your div as data-ng-include. It's proper usage is ng-include.

```
<div ng-include="'views/header.html'"></div>
```

Comment: if I change it to ng-include the problem persists. The header still displays but won't display on the registration page.

Comment: This is wrong. `data-ng-include` is the same as `ng-include`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18749115/1014979

Comment: Wow that is interesting I did not know that. Thank you for the information.