# How can i get evaluated expression from element attribute out of different scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have two different custom directives.
From one directive, I am calling an element from second directive with `angular.element` . That second element has an attribute that has an expression in it: `data-title="{{ widget.title }}`.

When I want to retrieve data-title via:

```
angular.element(ui.draggable).data('widget-title')
```

It's returning "{{ widget.title }}" and not the evaluated string. 
How can I retrieve data, not expression in first directive?

Comment: A little more code would be useful. But take a look at $observe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748739/angular-js-observe-on-directive-attribute

Comment: you could also do `$interpolate(angular.element(ui.draggable).data('widget-title'))`

Answer (score 0):

As pankajparkar said this is what you ought to do:

`$interpolate(angular.element(ui.draggable).data('widget-title'))($scope)`